# Datasources Provisioning In Grafana

Tags: grafana, provisioning

How can we provision Microsoft SQL Server Datasource in Grafana. Any sample of the YML file ?

My YML file looks like this:

```
apiVersion: 1

datasources:
- name: Microsoft SQL Server 
  # <string, required> datasource type. Required
  type: Microsoft SQL Server
  # <string, required> access mode. direct or proxy. Required
  access: proxy
  # <int> org id. will default to orgId 1 if not specified
  orgId: 1
  # <string> url
  #url: http://prometheus:9090/prometheus
  # <string> database password, if used
  password: 123
  # <string> database user, if used
  user: sa
  # <string> database name, if used
  database: jzcim4
  host: 192.168.1.77
  # <bool> enable/disable basic auth
  basicAuth: false
  # <string> basic auth username, if used
  basicAuthUser:
  # <string> basic auth password, if used
  basicAuthPassword:
  # <bool> enable/disable with credentials headers
  withCredentials:
  # <bool> mark as default datasource. Max one per org
  isDefault: true
```

but when i restart grafana  I get this "Unknown Plugin" error:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like below, which is currently working.

```
apiVersion: 1

datasources:
  - name: Microsoft SQL Server
    type: mssql
    url: 192.168.64.5:1433
    database: xxx
    user: sa
    jsonData:
      maxOpenConns: 0 # Grafana v5.4+
      maxIdleConns: 2 # Grafana v5.4+
      connMaxLifetime: 14400 # Grafana v5.4+
    secureJsonData:
      password: 'Xxad123312312'
```

Comment: Thanks . It worked . I realised that on the type I had placed Microsoft SQL Server instead of mssql